# Cannot mount Win10 virtual disk (VHD) with no volumes - DISKPART fail

Tags: windows, backup, restore, vhd, diskpart

I'm attempting to mount a Windows Image Backup .vhdx file and give it a drive letter so that I can retrieve a file or two out of the backup.  It has worked fine in the past, but now I cannot make it work with either of two backups from two separate systems.

In the past, I simply used Win10's Disk Management console to attach the VHD and assign a drive letter.  If Disk Management failed anywhere along the line, I'd have to use DISKPART to do it at the command line. There are many guides for this, including this one:
https://www.ubackup.com/articles/mount-windows-image-backup-vhd-4125.html

But now, even DISKPART cannot assign a drive letter to this VHD, because it reportedly has no volumes defined in it, and selecting the volume seems to be a requirement.

```
DISKPART> select vdisk file="\\rackstation\WindowsImageBackup\Jim-XPS\Backup 2021-05-18 205737\75a7e1c1-db22-4315-9afe-3852852949c8.vhdx"

DiskPart successfully selected the virtual disk file.

DISKPART> detail vdisk

Device type ID: 0 (Unknown)
Vendor ID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} (Unknown)
State: Attached not open
Virtual size: 1889 GB
Physical size:  598 GB
Filename: \\rackstation\WindowsImageBackup\Jim-XPS\Backup 2021-05-18 205737\75a7e1c1-db22-4315-9afe-3852852949c8.vhdx
Is Child: No
Parent Filename:
Associated disk#: 1

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online         1907 GB    11 MB        *
* Disk 1    Online         1889 GB   131 MB        *

DISKPART> detail disk

Microsoft Virtual Disk
Disk ID: {ABA28F86-D470-4402-9F03-9D1AA051BC33}
Type   : File Backed Virtual
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 1
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

There are no volumes.     **[ <== WTH?! ]**

DISKPART> list vdisk

  VDisk ###  Disk ###  State                 Type       File
  ---------  --------  --------------------  ---------  ----
[redacted list of other VDisks (#0 and #1) that are no longer attached, showing state of "Added", and lacking the asterisk you see below, left of "VDisk 2", denoting that it is "selected"]
* VDisk 2    Disk 1    Attached not open     Expandable  \\rackstation\WindowsImageBackup\Jim-XPS\Backup 2021-05-18 205737\75a7e1c1-db22-4315-9afe-3852852949c8.vhdx

DISKPART> assign letter M

There is no volume specified.
Please select a volume and try again.
```

Note that "list volume" returns a list of the volumes on Disk 0, rather than the selected Disk 1 (= VDisk 2), and "select volume [#]" does select the chosen volume, which then changes the selected disk to Disk 0 !  See below:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online         1907 GB    11 MB        *
* Disk 1    Online         1889 GB   131 MB        *

DISKPART> list volume    **[in spite of Disk 1 being selected, this will list volumes of Disk 0 because Disk 1 has no volumes]**

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   OS           NTFS   Partition   1888 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         ESP          FAT32  Partition    190 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2         WINRETOOLS   NTFS   Partition    990 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 3         Image        NTFS   Partition     16 GB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4         DELLSUPPORT  NTFS   Partition   1392 MB  Healthy    Hidden

DISKPART> select volume 0

Volume 0 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
* Disk 0    Online         1907 GB    11 MB        *
  Disk 1    Online         1889 GB   131 MB        *
```

So, what gives?  How do we mount the VHD files created by Windows Image Backup now?  And is this a known bug of DISKPART?  I can see where this silent switching of the selected disk could really screw the pooch if you were doing something destructive to your "selected" disk.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm dealing with exactly the same thing.

Comment: Sadly, no.  Sorry you're having the same issue.  I had Windows Information Protection (WIP) activated on my system at the time.  WIP is a total PoS, and I suspected it of having at least contributed to the problem, but I have no proof.  I'd be curious to know if you are also in that same boat.

Comment: To clarify the above.  WIP was on the host that created the windows image backup that was broken, not necessarily the machine running DISKPART.  I found that WIP reliably broke the backups and had to run a script to decrypt everything prior to creating the backup.  Joe, if you're in the same boat -- trying to mount a WIP-broken backup image, holler back, as I created a script to make them work.